# React Leaflet mouseover - change marker variable when hovering

Tags: reactjs, mouseover, react-leaflet

I want to change the marker icon variable when hovering. When hovering I want to set icon to divIconActive, and when not hovering to divIcon. I don't manage to make this work.

```
const Layers = () => {
  const [geoJson, setgeoJson] = useState([data]);
  const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState([false]);

  let iconSettings = {
    mapIconUrl:
      '<svg version="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 149 178"><path fill="{mapIconColor}" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M126 23l-6-6A69 69 0 0 0 74 1a69 69 0 0 0-51 22A70 70 0 0 0 1 74c0 21 7 38 22 52l43 47c6 6 11 6 16 0l48-51c12-13 18-29 18-48 0-20-8-37-22-51z"/><circle fill="{mapIconColorInnerCircle}" cx="74" cy="75" r="61"/><circle fill="#FFF" cx="74" cy="75" r="{pinInnerCircleRadius}"/></svg>',
    mapIconColor: "#7678a8",
    mapIconColorInnerCircle: "#fff",
    pinInnerCircleRadius: 48,
  };

  // icon normal state
  let divIcon = L.divIcon({
    className: "leaflet-data-marker",
    html: L.Util.template(iconSettings.mapIconUrl, iconSettings), //.replace('#','%23'),
    iconAnchor: [12, 32],
    iconSize: [25, 30],
    popupAnchor: [0, -28],
  });

  let divIconActive = L.divIcon({
    className: "leaflet-data-marker",
    html: L.Util.template(iconSettings.mapIconUrl, iconSettings), //.replace('#','%23'),
    iconAnchor: [18, 42],
    iconSize: [40, 42],
    popupAnchor: [0, -30],
  });

  const getMarkerPosition = (city) => {
    switch (city) {
      case "Växjö":
        return [56.8787183, 14.8094385];
      case "Sundsvall":
        return [62.40766, 16.93196];
      case "Lund":
        return [55.42, 13.1124];
      default:
        return;
    }
  };

  const handleIconSize = () => {
    if (!isHovering) {
      setIsHovering(true);
    } else {
      setIsHovering(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      {[...geoJson[0].features].map((item) => {
        const city = item.properties.display_name;

        return (
          <>
            <LayerGroup>
              <GeoJSON data={item.geometry}>
                <Marker
                  position={getMarkerPosition(city)}
                  icon={isHovering ? divIconActive : divIcon}
                  onMouseOver={(event) => event.target.handleIconSize()}
                >
                  <Popup>{city}</Popup>
                </Marker>
              </GeoJSON>
            </LayerGroup>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Layers;
```

Here is my map file:

```
const Map = () => {
  const sweden = [62.5454, 17.2248];

  return (
    <div>
      <MapContainer
        style={{
          height: "100%",
          width: "800px",
          boxShadow: "0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.3)",
        }}
        center={sweden}
        zoom={5}
        zoomControl={true}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>'
          url="https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        ></TileLayer>
        <Layers />
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9lwH.png)

I've tried to use eventhandlers in the Marker component, but that didn't work either.
Any input is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to leverage eventHandlers.

```js
<Marker
  position={getMarkerPosition(city)}
  icon={isHovering ? divIconActive : divIcon}
  eventHandlers={{
    mouseover: () => setIsHovering(true),
    mouseout: () => setIsHovering(false),
  }}
>
```

Also create a wrapper for the marker so you can keep the isHovering state on each marker.